# Script does not execute simultaneously in Linux

Tags: linux, bash

I have 10 servers and I access them using jumpbox. I wrote a script for starting a service on each server. When I execute that script it's only run on one server and after pressing `Ctrl+C` it's executed on the next server and so on. I want to run it on all servers without pressing `Ctrl+C`.

This is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `cat /etc/hosts | grep prod | awk '{print $2}'` ;
do
ssh $i "hostname && sudo service name start"
done;
```

Comment: Make sure your user is allowed to execute `sudo service name start` without entering a password.

Comment: @Cyrus yes no issue with sudo

Comment: I guess there is a problem with output redirection in your service script.

Comment: I, too, think you''re problems depend standard file redirections. You could try to add option `-n` to _ssh_ and to end the command-line with `&`. As a last comment, you can replace the three sub-processes `cat /etc/hosts | grep prod | awk '{print $2}'` with just one sub-process `awk '/prod/ {print $2}' /etc/hosts`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `&` to fork new process.

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `cat /etc/hosts | grep prod | awk '{print $2}'` ;
do
ssh $i "hostname && sudo service name start" &
done;
```